# PL/SQL Static cursor variable as ref cursor

Tags: plsql, ref-cursor, sys-refcursor

I have a procedure that takes a SYS_REFCURSOR and converts it to JSON.

In a procedure that calls the above, I'm trying define a CURSOR as normal and supply that as a REF CURSOR.

I'm receiving PLS-00361.

I understand that I can use the OPEN FOR construct, but I need to use my Cursor elsewhere and don't like the duplication.

Any advice?

```
  PROCEDURE LIST_EMPLOYEES 
  AS

    l_ref_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;

    CURSOR c_emps
    IS
    SELECT email_address
      FROM employees;

  BEGIN

    OPEN c_emps;
    FETCH c_emps INTO l_ref_cursor;

    json_utils.refcursor_to_json_via_http(l_ref_cursor,
                                          'employees');

    CLOSE l_ref_cursor;

  EXCEPTION
  WHEN others
  THEN
    log_error;
  END LIST_EMPLOYEES;
```

Regards,
Laurence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't fetch the cursor into the REF CURSOR, you would simply OPEN it:

```
PROCEDURE LIST_EMPLOYEES AS

   l_ref_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;

BEGIN

   OPEN l_ref_cursor FOR SELECT email_address FROM employees;

   json_utils.refcursor_to_json_via_http(l_ref_cursor, 'employees');

   CLOSE l_ref_cursor;

END LIST_EMPLOYEES;
```

Comment: Thanks Vincent,  I understand I can do that, but what if I want to do this multiple times?  I would have to repeat my cursor over and over.

Comment: If you need this cursor more than once, create a function that returns a SYS_REFCURSOR and call that function instead: `json.refcursor_to_json_via_http(my_function, 'employees');`